# Resolve Object namepath with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
const list = {
    library: {
        books: {
            count: 100
        }
    }
}
```

And I have an array:

```
const key = [ 'library', 'books', 'count' ]
```

I’d like to get the value `100` from the object using that array.

I’ve tried just using the array:

```js
const list = {
    library: {
        books: {
            count: 100
        }
    }
}

const key = [ 'library', 'books', 'count' ]

console.log(list[key])
```

No surprises here, returns `undefined`.

And I’ve tried converting it to a string:

```js
const list = {
    library: {
        books: {
            count: 100
        }
    }
}

const key = [ 'library', 'books', 'count' ]

console.log(list[key.toString()])
```

Again obviously returns `undefined`.

I can of course just loop through the object using the array – but I was hoping that somebody knew of a lovely one-liner that would work like magic.

Comment: In ruby this is called `dig`. Maybe something like that exists in JS stdlib or popular libraries, but at worst, you can implement this yourself and hide it as a library function.

Comment: With [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get), for example: `_.get(list, "library.books.count")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most succinct way I know is with `reduce`:

```js
const list = {
    library: {
        books: {
            count: 100
        }
    }
}

const key = [ 'library', 'books', 'count' ]

// simple one-liner
let val = key.reduce((obj,key) => obj[key], list)
console.log(val)
```

Of course, you'll probably want to do some checks if you're dealing with inconsistent data.

You can also use a recursive function but not quite as short:

```js
const list = {
    library: {
        books: {
            count: 100
        }
    }
}

const key = [ 'library', 'books', 'count' ]

function getKey(obj, list) {
    let key = list.shift()
    if (key === undefined) return
    let val = obj[key]
    if (typeof val !== 'object') return val
    return getKey(val, list)

}

let val = getKey(list, key)
console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to implement is known as a **namepath resolution**.
You can achieve it, using `reduce`, or a regular `for` iteration.

I've prepared some benchmarks here :
[Performance test : reduce vs for loop](https://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-for-iteration/)

**The `for loop`, is aparently 10% faster than `reduce`**

*( tested in Chrome 65.0.3325 / Windows 10 0.0.0 )*

---

## For loop

**Faster**, and maybe easier to understand.

```js
// namepath resolver 
function resolvePath(target, namepath){
    for( let i=0 ; i< namepath.length;i++ ) target = target[namepath[i] ];
    return target;
};

// your target
const list = {
    library: {
        books: {
            count: 100
        }
    }
};
// your namepath
const key = [ 'library', 'books', 'count' ];

alert( resolvePath(list, key) ) // outputs 100
```

---

## Array.prototype.reduce() (since ES5)

Shorter and more elegant, but less intuitive at the beggining. And according to my performance tests, **slower**.

Usage: [Mozilla Developer Documentation of Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
// your target
const list = {
    library: {
        books: {
            count: 100
        }
    }
};
// your namepath
const key = [ 'library', 'books', 'count' ];

alert ( key.reduce((target,key) => target[key], list) )
```

---

## Suicidal mode

If you don't care about security, and you are in the mood of entering the **real danger zone**...

`eval( 'list.' + key.join('.') )`

Definitely the shortest :D

**(don't even think about using this)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this. A shorter version. Just for fun :)

```js
const list = {
    library: {
        books: {
            count: 100
        }
    }
}
const key = [ 'library', 'books', 'count' ]
console.log(list[key[0]][key[1]][key[2]])
```

Comment: LOL : `eval('list.'+key.join('.'))`